# Upload a Product Image to Shopify via PHP API

Tags: php, shopify

I am trying to upload a Product Image to Shopify via POST-ing a Base64 image to the API with OhShopify PHP library fork.

I have other code which successfully creates the product, but this snippet below returns NULL and I can't pinpoint why.

This code runs seemingly successfully 'makes it' and creates a new ShopifyClient object, but the var_dump on the $response['src'] returns NULL and the image never makes it.  Am I missing something?

```
<?php

define('SHOPIFY_API_KEY', 'abc');
define('SHOPIFY_SECRET', '123');
define('SHOPIFY_SCOPE', 'write_content,write_products,write_orders');

include_once('lib/ohShopify/shopify.php');

// Check for shopify authentication
if (isset($_SESSION['shop']) && isset($_SESSION['token'])){

    $shopifyClient = new ShopifyClient($_SESSION['shop'], $_SESSION['token'], SHOPIFY_API_KEY, SHOPIFY_SECRET); 
    echo 'made it';

} else{
    echo 'token and shop not set up';
}


$testBase64 = "loooooooooooooong string of text";

try {
    $theImages = array
    (
        "image"=>array
        (
            "position" =>    1,
            "attachment" =>  $testBase64
        )
    );

    $response = $shopifyClient->call('POST', '/admin/products/#326021139/images.json', $theImages);

    var_dump($response['src']);

} catch (ShopifyApiException $ex) {
    var_dump($ex);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The images array is 1 more array :

$image = file_get_contents("Images/test.jpg");
$base64 = base64_encode($image);

```
    $products_array = array
    (
        'product' => array
        (
            'title' => $_POST['title'],
            'body_html' => $_POST['body_html'],
            'vendor' => $_POST['vendor'],
            'product_type' => $_POST['type'],
            'images' => array(
                            array(
                            'filename' => 'test.jpg',
                            'attachment' => $base64
                            )
                        )
        )
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

If you base64 encode your image, it also works from local files.
The only thing you did wrong was the extra array at images:

```php
  $image = file_get_contents("Images/test.jpg");
  $base64 = base64_encode($image);
  $products_array = array
  (
    'product' => array
  (
    'title' => $_POST['title'],
    'body_html' => $_POST['body_html'],
    'vendor' => $_POST['vendor'],
    'product_type' => $_POST['type'],
    'images' => array(
        array(
        'filename' => 'test.jpg',
          'attachment' => $base64
      )
    )
  )
);
```

Answer (score -1):

**Stack Overflow suffers with all the drive-by zealots down voting posts/questions without a statement as to their reasons.  If you have a reason, then please pontificate rather then being an anonymous coward.**

For those having the same issue or question, I ultimately could NOT get this to work but came up with a solution that I would initially take the base64 encoded image, save it as a file on server, then pass the URL of the file to a Product creation API call.

Essentially:

```
file_put_contents( 'img_uploads/'.$filename, base64_decode($encoded_img) );
...
try {
    // Create a new product
    $product = array
    (
        "product"=>array
        (
            "title"=>$title,
            "body_html"=>$body_html,
            "vendor"=>$vendor,
            "product_type"=>$productType,
            "variants"=>array ("price"=>$price),
            "images"=>array ("src"=>$image)
        )
    );
    $response = $shopifyClient->call('POST', '/admin/products.json', $product);
```

Comment: please explain what $image is

Comment: The post result of the image upload.  When I can dig up the code and update this further, I will